# How to resolve getSupportFragmentManager and getFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am very new in android programming and i am confused, which library should be used.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment start_frag = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if(start_frag == null) {
            start_frag = new CM_youtubePlaylist();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, start_frag).commit();
        }
```

I am stuck in between android.app.FragmentManager and android.support.v4.FragmentManager. Actually i have imported both of them, and now it is showing error, which is quite obvious. What I want to ask, which library should i use and which one is better between both of them?

Answer (score 1):

For  API >= 14,  use getFragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `Fragment` type to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to which you are switching. And Let `FragmentManager` be `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: problem solved. I had import corresponding fragment liberary.

Comment: thats what i was saying